# Drupal 8 Guzzle Format Query String

Tags: post, guzzle, drupal-8

Forgive me for my ignorance, this is my first attempt at Drupal 8 and I'm not a good php developer to begin with. But I've been reading and searching for hours. I'm trying to do a post using the new Guzzle that replaces the drupal_http_request(). I've done this using Curl but can't seem to get this going in the right direction here. I'm just not "getting it".

Here is a sample of the array I have that pulls data from a custom form. I also tried this with a custom variable where I built the string.

```
$fields = array(
   "enroll_id" => $plan,
   "notice_date" => $date,
   "effective_date" => $date,
);

$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$response = $client->post('myCustomURL', ['query' => $fields]);
$data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
try { 
drupal_set_message($data);
} catch (RequestException $e) {
watchdog_exception('MyCustomForm', $e->getMessage());
}
```

This indeed returns the result of REJECTED from my API in $data below - but it doesn't append the URL to included the query => array. I've tried numerous combinations of this just putting the fully built URL in the post (that works with my API - tested) and I still receive the same result from my API. In the end what I'm trying to accomplish is

```
https://myCustomURL?enroll_id=value&notice_date=12/12/12&effective_date=12/12/12
```

Any direction or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses guys. I was able to get it to work correctly by changing a few things in my post. First changing *client -> post* to a *request('POST', XXX)* and then changing *"query"* to *"form_params"* as *"body"* has been deprecated.

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

```
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$response = $client->request('POST','https://myURL.html', ['form_params' => $fields]);
$data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: I had to change $client->post to request('POST, XXX) as well to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$client->post` will send a POST request. By looking at the URL that you tested directly you want a GET request.

Either use `$client->get` or `$client->request` with the GET parameter. More information and examples in the [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters).